# Scroll View Not Responding in flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview

My Scrollview not Responding, can someone tell what I am missing in code:

Please Suggest me how to add scroll view listener I'm beginner.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import 'favourite_articles.dart';
import 'coin_system.dart';

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  bool _notification = false;
  ScrollController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkNotificationSetting();
  }

  checkNotificationSetting() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'notification';
    final value = prefs.getInt(key) ?? 0;
    if (value == 0) {
      setState(() {
        _notification = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _notification = true;
      });
    }
  }

  saveNotificationSetting(bool val) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'notification';
    final value = val ? 1 : 0;
    prefs.setInt(key, value);
    if (value == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _notification = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _notification = false;
      });
    }
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'More',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
        ),
        elevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
              color: Colors.black,
              tooltip: 'Song Request',
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => CoinSystem(),
                  ),
                );
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _controller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 10),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/icon.png'),
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 20),
                child: Text(
                  "Version 2.1.0 \n ",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(height: 1.6, color: Colors.black87),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 10,
                thickness: 2,
              ),
              //ListWheelScrollView(
              ListView(
                //itemExtent: 75,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => FavouriteArticles(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Image.asset(
                        "assets/more/favourite.png",
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      title: Text('Favourite'),
                      subtitle: Text("See the saved songs"),
                    ),
                  ),

                  //Song Request Code
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CoinSystem(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Image.asset(
                        "assets/more/songrequest.png",
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      title: Text('Songs Request'),
                      subtitle: Text("Request your favourite songs"),
                    ),
                  ),

                  //Song Request Code End

                  
                  
                  
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Image.asset(
                      "assets/more/notification.png",
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    title: Text('Notification'),
                    subtitle: Text("Change notification preference"),
                    trailing: Switch(
                        onChanged: (val) async {
                          await saveNotificationSetting(val);
                        },
                        value: _notification),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      //),
    );
    //);
  }
}
```

So, I have tried SingleChildScrollView, in that I have Container and Listview. But Listview doesn't response on scrolling action in landscape mode.

I have added ScrollController _controller; Do i have to create _controller class that listern the scrolling action?

Comment: I tried your code and it is scrolling, i can scroll ListView's items and the container with the list view too if i scrolled at the top. What the problem you faced exactly ? did you tried to restar the app ?

Comment: I have remove ListView and changed all widgets inside separate containers works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, you want to be able to get 2 scrolling. 1. using SingleChildScrollView and inside that Widget, you want to be able to scroll the bottom layer, thus you use ListView. To make it work, you have to place your ListView inside widget that has certain height. Example this implementation is:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(child: Text('Upper scrollable'), height: 450),
          Divider(
            height: 10,
            thickness: 2,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 350,
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color:Colors.red,
                  child: SizedBox(child: Text('Bottom scrollable'), height: 450),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

If you don't want to use 2 scroll, don't use ListView inside SingleChildScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

1. ListView cannot be wrapped with SingleChildScrollView remove it
2. surround ListView with Expanded Widget

try one of the two alternatives.